# How to optimize the for loop for finding a matching 2 string using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, list, fuzzywuzzy

I am getting the probability of a string being similar to another string in Python using `fuzzywuzzy` lib.

Currently, I am doing this using a for loop and the search is time consuming.

Below is working code  :

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

with open('all_nut_data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
   spamwriter = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
   mostsimilarcs = 0
   mostsimilarns = 0
   for rowdata in spamwriter:
       mostsimilarns = fuzz.ratio(rowdata["Food Item"].lower(), name.lower())
       if mostsimilarns > mostsimilarcs:
           mostsimilarcs = mostsimilarns
           row1 = rowdata
```

How I can optimize this code without for loop?

Note* CSV file contain 600,000 rows and 17 column

Comment: Ask on [codereview stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @shaik moeed why ?

Comment: Read [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to know *why?* You need to add `performance` tag to your question.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229963/how-to-optimize-the-for-loop-for-finding-a-matching-2-string-using-fuzzywuzzy